# Render object properties with one line

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

How to display every property in checkbox inside one line
I have object features which have many properties, these properties are dynamically assigned and I do not want to hard code these in the view.
So, right now I have something like these

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Features.IsRegistered, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Features.IsPhone, new { @disabled = "disabled"
```

.... and many more

how to render exactly like these above but for all object properties, is this possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've only done some limited testing with this, but here's a basic implementation of an extension method you can play with:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxesForModel(this HtmlHelper helper,
        object model)
    {
        if (model == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("'model' is null");

        return CheckBoxesForModel(helper, model.GetType());
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxesForModel(this HtmlHelper helper,
        Type modelType)
    {
        if (modelType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("'modelType' is null");

        string output = string.Empty;
        var properties = modelType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var property in properties)
            output += helper.CheckBox(property.Name, new { @disabled = "disabled" });

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(output);
    }
}
```

You may wish to expand on it to allow it to take HTML attributes as well, rather than hard-coding them, but this should get you started.